# Woocommerce dashboard template text change

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I faced with an issue, which already makes me mad. I want to change the text of the woocommerce dashboard (the template text), but if I change something in the php files nothing changes. I tried both files:

```
...wp_content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/myaccount/dashboard.php 
...wp_content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/dashboard.php
```

I checked already 25+ forums without luck.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Are you using any cache plugins?

Comment: I have already deleted all of the cache data from the browser, but it did not help. I do not know about additional cache plugins, I tried Phoeniixx which is able to customize it, but it can only bind additional text and will not override the original text. But at the end there was no change with and without Phoeniixx.

Comment: maybe silly question, but are you sure that you are editing active theme's file? you wrote wp_content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/myaccount/dashboard.php and may it be that mytheme is not your currently active theme?  also, you can activate another woo theme and try it with that. in that case you will know that if it is theme related issue or not.

Comment: I welcome every questions, there should be something what I am doing wrong. So to answer your question "mytheme" is active. I am using Listable theme and it is compatible with the version of the woo what I am using actually.

Comment: I found a solution. I have downloaded the language file and translated it with the text I wanted to have there. Another solution is the Say what plugin. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: double check it is in ...mytheme/woocommerce/myaccount/dashboard.php and not  ...mytheme/woocommerce/templates/myaccount/dashboard.php.